# Microsoft Bing Speech API using Python: No JSON Object

Tags: python, rest, microsoft-speech-api

I'm trying to implement the Microsoft Bing Speech REST API with Python and I've found some code online.

https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/02/09/getting-started-with-speech-to-text

```
import json
import requests

    YOUR_API_KEY = 'ENTER_YOUR_KEY_HERE'
    YOUR_AUDIO_FILE = 'ENTER_PATH_TO_YOUR_AUDIO_FILE_HERE'
    MODE = 'interactive'
    LANG = 'en-US'
    FORMAT = 'simple'


    def handler():
        # 1. Get an Authorization Token
        token = get_token()
        # 2. Perform Speech Recognition
        results = get_text(token, YOUR_AUDIO_FILE)
        # 3. Print Results
        print(results)

    def get_token():
        # Return an Authorization Token by making a HTTP POST request to Cognitive Services with a valid API key.
        url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken'
        headers = {
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': YOUR_API_KEY
        }
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
        token = r.content
        return(token)

    def get_text(token, audio):
        # Request that the Bing Speech API convert the audio to text
        url = 'https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/{0}/cognitiveservices/v1?language={1}&format={2}'.format(MODE, LANG, FORMAT)
        headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': YOUR_API_KEY,
            'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
            'Content-type': 'audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)
        }
        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=stream_audio_file(audio))
        results = json.loads(r.content)
        return results

    def stream_audio_file(speech_file, chunk_size=1024):
        # Chunk audio file
        with open(speech_file, 'rb') as f:
            while 1:
                data = f.read(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                yield data

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        handler()
```

I've followed the above code (and changed the key and audio file name) but keep getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emi/Desktop/proj/taygan tutorial/handler.py", line 55, in <module>
    handler()
  File "/Users/emi/Desktop/proj/taygan tutorial/handler.py", line 15, in handler
    results = get_text(token, YOUR_AUDIO_FILE)
  File "/Users/emi/Desktop/proj/taygan tutorial/handler.py", line 40, in get_text
    results = json.loads(r.content)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Complete newbie so really don't understand what's going on. Thanks!

NOTE: I've also tried the code from this 
[GitHub Repos](https://gist.github.com/jellis505/973ea6de12508c7c720da4a074e7d065)
but I receive many errors with this one.

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question!

Comment: @KlausD. sorry did it!

Comment: You are not checking the http response code. You might receive an error message in the body without knowing.